# Rows restriction within a function

Tags: google-apps-script

I've written 99 rows of code within my function. And when I had trying to add a new one(just by clicking Enter inside), I have seen that color of my function curly brackets changed from green to red.
It seems like in-built restriction of google apps script, but I haven't found anything about it...
So, what is the reason of changing color? Are there other technical restrictions exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only a limitation of the syntax highlighting within the Script Editor, your function will still execute as normal, even if it is much longer than 100 lines.

I have noticed this on many occasions and wasted some time trying to find the cause, thinking it was due to a syntax error in my code. Eventually I realized that if there was too much space between the braces the highlighting no longer worked. However I didn't know the limit was precisely 100 lines, so thank you for that information :)